# Including this file causes a bunch of unknown type errors [C]

Tags: c

Including `main.h` in `stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h` causes issues --> `usart_app.h:14:22: error: unknown type name 'USART_Handle_t'; did you mean 'DMA_Handle_t'?` -- mainly related to unknown types.

Aren't there easy ways around figuring out issues specific to file includes? cause it's annoying

I suspect `stm32f4xx_dma.h` is causing trouble since it's being called in `main.h` and `stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h` but I wonder wouldn't header guard take care of the 'loop`?

here's what i sort of have:

````
// --- main.h ---
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include "mcp9808.h"
#include "usart_app.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_dma.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// --- stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h ---"
#include <stdint.h>
#include "stdbool.h"
#include "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_dma.h"
#include "main.h" // ... adding this causes issues !!

typedef struct {
    USART_TypeDef *pUSARTx;
    USART_Config_t USART_Config;
    USART_State USART_State;
    char *txBuffer;
    char *rxBuffer;
    uint8_t txLength;
    uint8_t rxLength;
    uint8_t rxSize;
    uint8_t dmaTransfer;
    uint8_t dmaReception;
    DMA_Handle_t *dmaRx;
    DMA_Handle_t *dmaTx;
} USART_Handle_t;

// --- stm32f4xx_dma.h ---
#include "stm32f401xe.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"```
````

Comment: You have circular includes. `stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.h` includes `stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h` and it includes `main.h` that includes...

Comment: Any particular reason why `#include "stm32f4xx_dma.h"` is included 3 times ?

Comment: um, isn't this solely why header guards exist?

Comment: Header guards protect against including the same file twice. But note that headers include themselves before they define symbols, because we put `#include` on the top of the file (correctly). So once you enter a file, then you enter dependency that includes that file again, it will not be scanned because the include guard is defined already. (Ach it's hard to explain. There is even a wiki article about it - research the topic). On a side note decide if you use stm32 hal libraries or peripheral library.

Comment: @DNT my bad. ignore the include of `stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h` in main. ill remove it, but the issue persists still

Comment: Is `USART_Handle_t` a `typedef` or a `#define` ? If the latter,is there something in `main.h` that undefs it ?

Comment: @DNT i have included the definition of `USART_Handle_t` in the snippet. it's a `typedef`

Comment: @KamilCuk so even if each file that's included has a guard defined, it would still create a circular includes? how would you separate it out?

Answer (score 0):

> …  I wonder wouldn't header guard take care of the 'loop`?

What header guard? The file contents you show in the question do not have header guards.

If there are header guards, then the problem is that including `main.h` in `stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h` causes it to include `usart_app.h`, and `usart_app.h` needs the `USART_Handle_t` defined in `stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h`, so it includes `stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h`, but the earlier processing is already past the header guard in `stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h`, so the guard skips the body of `stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h` when `usart_app.h` includes it, so `USART_Handle_t` is not defined.

To fix that, do not include `main.h` in `stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h`.

Comment: I see. But what if I want to reference a function located in `main.c` inside `stm32f4xx_hal_uart.c` though? And sorry I didn't show header guards in the snippet, but they're being used

Comment: @Pokloha: `main.h` should only have includes that are necessary for declarations that `main.c` exports, not for things otherwise used by `main.c`. Move all includes possible from `main.h` to `main.c`.

Comment: @Pokloha: In the future, include **all** information needed to reproduce your problem. Provide a [mre]. Excluding the header guards is grounds for closing the question.